# позиционирование canvas в html

Tags: javascript, html, css

столкнулся с проблемой, не могу поставить canvas в нижний левый угол страницы и дико туплю

Comment: ахахах. извините, не удержался. Просто не могу никак состыковать ваши подобные вопросы и "уникальный секретный проект, который перевернёт весь мир"

Comment: ))) я с одной проблемы на другую перескакиваю, вчера оптимизацию делал, сёдня всё три стороны удалил, и вот...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В простейшем случае `bottom: 0` прижмет к низу, но для того чтобы он действовал нужно выбрать  `position: absolute`

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, но я уже решил проблему костылями)))